# splitting and joining parameters in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to create a simple MLP. I have a parameter set [W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3] where W is 2-d and b is 1-d. I want to concatenate the parameter set to one vector and I did this:

```
    learnable_param_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
    learnable_param = tf.concat(1, [[tf.reshape(param, [-1])] for param in learnable_param_list], name='learnable_paramVector')
```

This seems to work. Now I want to update learnable_param_list with a single vector. I tried

```
    learnable_param_assign_split = tf.split_v(split_dim=0, value=learnable_param_assign_placeholder, size_splits=[tf.size(param) for param in learnable_param_list])
    for idx, param_list in learnable_param_list:
        reshaped_input_vector = tf.reshape(learnable_param_assign_split[idx], shape=tf.shape(param_list))
        assignLearnableParam_op_list += [param_list.assign(learnable_param_assign_placeholder)]
```

This does not work. I get many errors like "variable not iterable" and zero size tensors. How can I split a vector and assign it to multiple tensors of different shapes?

Comment: I added enumerate in for loop and replaced size_splits to number tuple, then it worked. But I was hoping that there is a way not assigning parameter size manually...

Comment: I figure out the answer. The split_size can be replaced [reduce(mul, param.get_shape().as_list(), 1) for param in learnable_param_list]

Comment: could you copy your comment into an answer so others know it's solved?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the answer. The split_size can be replaced [reduce(mul, param.get_shape().as_list(), 1) for param in learnable_param_list]